# How do I make the quotations in this script clickable link?

Tags: javascript

I have this script from codelifter and it works great.
I would like that if the quotations below contained a url then it would become clickable.
Any help would be great.
Thanks

```
<script language="JavaScript">
// ==============================================
// Copyright 2004 by CodeLifter.com
// Free for all; but please leave in this header.
// ==============================================

var Quotation=new Array() // do not change this!

// Set up the quotations to be shown, below.
// To add more quotations, continue with the
// pattern, adding to the array.  Remember
// to increment the Quotation[x] index!

Quotation[0] = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zH6U5y086hw";
Quotation[1] = "Sanity is a golden apple with no shoelaces.";
Quotation[2] = "Repent! The end is coming, $9.95 at Amazon.";
Quotation[3] = "Honesty blurts where deception sneezes.";
Quotation[4] = "Pastry satisfies where art is unavailable.";
Quotation[5] = "Delete not, lest you, too, be deleted.";
Quotation[6] = "O! Youth! What a pain in the backside.";
Quotation[7] = "Wishes are like goldfish with propellors.";
Quotation[8] = "Love the river's \"beauty\", but live on a hill.";
Quotation[9] = "Invention is the mother of too many useless toys.";

// ======================================
// Do not change anything below this line
// ======================================
var Q = Quotation.length;
var whichQuotation=Math.round(Math.random()*(Q-1));
function showQuotation(){document.write(Quotation[whichQuotation]);}
showQuotation();
</script>
```

Comment: stick an anchor tag in there.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

1. Assume quotation begins with http(s)://
2. In ShowQuotation: <strike>Use a regexp to identify such strings.</strike> Might be unnecessarily complicated. Check if a length-7 substring is `http://` OR length-8 substring is `https://` , assume the rest is all part of the URL
3. Make it a link

Answer (score 1):

```
function showQuotation(){
    if(Quotation[whichQuotation].substr(0,7)=='http://' || Quotation[whichQuotation].substr(0,8)=='https://')
    document.write('<a href="'+Quotation[whichQuotation]+'">'+Quotation[whichQuotation]+'</a>');
    else
    document.write(Quotation[whichQuotation]);
}
```

Comment: A little dirty, but it works based on the provided info. Probably work better if you did a match against string and extracted the link, allowing for custom link text. Pattern matching is great for short-coding url's and using jquery or javascript to replace the shortcode with a link and text.

Comment: Thanks Elias. Just what I wanted